# Exact NOT(Inverse) of CSS Media Query

Tags: html, css, w3c, media-queries

What is the exact "NOT" of the following CSS media query ?

```
@media only screen and (device-width:768px)
```

Just to add, it would mean..All EXCEPT iPAD...OR.....NOT iPAD..

and BTW...I have already tried

```
@media not only screen and (device-width:768px)
```

which does not work..

Comment: By the way, assuming that anything with a 758px wide screen is an iPad seems like a bad idea....

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
@media not screen and (device-width:768px)
```

`not` and `only` are mutually exclusive in media queries; `only` is needed only to work around some downrev UAs who implement the HTML4 algorithm for media strings, so when the query starts with `not` the `only` is pointless.

Comment: Ok..Cool..Will @media not screen and (device-width:768px) work in IE8 ?

Comment: IE8 doesn't support media queries at all.  So that media query will be treated as an unknown medium and not match.

Comment: IE8 and below can use a media query if it is forced to. These work: @media \0screen { color:red; } /* media query to target ie8 */

Comment: IE8-: @media \0screen\,screen\9 { color:red; } /* media query to target ie6-8 (ie8-) */