# Combined inverted media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I have sass code that generates a negated media query as follow (based on [Exact NOT(Inverse) of CSS Media Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766069/exact-notinverse-of-css-media-query)):

```
@media not screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .phone {
        display: none; 
    } 
}
@media not screen and (min-width: 421px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .tablet {
        display: none; 
    } 
}
```

Why doesn't this work for the last div with combined classes?

```
<div class="phone">visible on: phone</div>
<div class="tablet">visible on: tablet</div>
<div class="phone tablet">visible on: phone and tablet</div>
```

The reason I'm inverting the logic is because if I would do it the other way around (showing instead of hiding). I wouldn't know what display type each element would be (block, inline, etc) and I [can't set it back to it's previous value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value).

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tgLvxsw8/show) and [source](https://jsfiddle.net/tgLvxsw8/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div class="phone tablet"/>` cannot be visible any time, because all time at least one of your 2 media queries are matched, so this `div` gets a `display: none` from at least one of those.

One solution would be

```
@media not screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .phone:not(.tablet) {
        display: none;
    } 
}
@media not screen and (min-width: 421px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .tablet:not(.phone) {
        display: none; 
    } 
}
```

Update to your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgLvxsw8/2/).

If you also want the `div` in question be hidden if both, `.phone` and `.tablet` are hidden, add

```
@media not screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .phone.tablet {
        display: none; 
    } 
}
```

Another update to your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgLvxsw8/3/).